# How to save data from text file to python dictionary and select designation data

Tags: python, dictionary

Example of data in txt file:

```
apple
orange
banana
lemon
pears
```

Code of filtering words with 5 letters without dictionary:

```
def numberofletters(n):
    file = open("words.txt","r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) == 6:
            print(line)       

    return

print("===================================================================")
print("This program can use for identify and print out all words in 5 
letters from words.txt")
n = input("Please Press enter to start filtering words")
print("===================================================================")
numberofletters(n)
```

My question is how create a dictionary whose keys are integers and values the English words with that many letters and Use the dictionary to identify and print out all the 5 letter words?

Imaging with a huge list of words

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for a `defaultdict`.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> length2words = defaultdict(set)
>>> 
>>> with open('file.txt') as f:
...     for word in f: # one word per line
...         word = word.strip()
...         length2words[len(word)].add(word)
... 
>>> length2words[5]
set(['lemon', 'apple', 'pears'])
```

If you care about duplicates and insertion order, use a `defaultdict(list)` and `append` instead of `add`.

Comment: How to do it without any import functions?

Comment: collections is part of the standard python library, importing it should not be an issue. But if it is you can just use a dict of arrays(so wordcount[5] = []) and then just do a check to see if it exists on every insert to the sub-array so that you don't crash  the program)

Answer (score 0):

you can make your for loop like this:

```
for line in lines:
    line_len = len(line)
    if line_len not in dicword.keys():
        dicword.update({line_len: [line]})
    else:
        dicword[line_len].append(line)
```

Then you can get it by just doing `dicword[5]`

Comment: Why use `update` here instead of just `dicword[line_len] = [line]`?

Comment: No particular reason other than just my habit.

Comment: Can you show my how the code run (all of it)? I try to input to mine , but its not work. Thanks

Comment: Just replace your for loop inside the function with that, and your return should be `return dicword[n]`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, you need to write filter your document and result into a file. For that you can write a CSV file with DictWriter (*https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html*).

> **DictWriter**: Create an object which operates like a regular writer but maps dictionaries onto output rows.

BTW, you will be able to store and structure your document

```
def numberofletters(n):
   file = open("words.txt","r")
   lines = file.readlines()
   file.close()
   dicword = {}
   writer = csv.DictWriter(filename, fieldnames=fieldnames)
   writer.writeheader()
   for line in lines:
       if len(line) == 6:
           writer.writerow({'param_label': line, [...]})
   return
```

I hope that help you.